# Edit Data with Bootstrap Modal Window in Laravel 5.8

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

each time i update the data it redirecting on http://localhost:8000/indicprocs/indicprocs/test this and there this page not found (404|not found). I have update form action = route('indicprocs.update','test') and a hidden field also for id. how can i solve this problem please ?

```
public function update(Request $request)
{       $indicatorsproc = indicatorsproc::findOrFail($request->indicator_id);

        $indicatorsproc->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('indicprocs.index')
        ->with('success','project updated successfully');
}
```

```js
<script>
  $('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var name = button.data('myname')
    var detail = button.data('mydetail')
    var ind_id = button.data('indicid')
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-body #name').val(name);
    modal.find('.modal-body #detail').val(detail);
    modal.find('.modal-body #ind_id').val(ind_id);

  })
</script>
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Category</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

      </div>
      <form action="{{route('indicprocs.update','test')}}" method="post">
        {{method_field('patch')}} {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="hidden" name="indicator_id" id="indic_id" value=""> @include('indicprocs.form')
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you defined route for `http://localhost:8000/indicprocs/indicprocs/test` ?

Comment: show your route file ?

Comment: i used Route::resource('indicprocs/indicprocs','IndicatorsprocController'); in the route file .

Comment: i solved it , i find that the value of  hiden field is empty then i correct the name of id in Javascript from                                                                   var ind_id = button.data('indicid')                 modal.find('.modal-body #ind_id').val(ind_id);
 to                                                                       var indic_id = button.data('indicid')                 
 modal.find('.modal-body #indic_id').val(indic_id);     thank you so much